# Migrating a django form into Ajax gives ValueError

Tags: ajax, django

I have a django app with several form that I am trying to migrate to ajax.  I am doing this because I want to update my data without refreshing my screen.  I used the dajax library and started moving some of my views.py code into ajax.py.

I am getting a "ValueError: too many values to unpack " in code that worked fine in views.py.  I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.  Advice?

ajax.py

```
def send_student_form(request, form):
  dajax = Dajax()
  #error is here
  student = Student.objects.get( form.get('student_id'))
  #student = Student()  # no ValueError, but it doesn't find my student.
  if student:
    print "Student Found!"
    sForm = StudentProfileForm(request.POST, instance=student) 
    print student
  else:
    print "Student Not Found"
    sForm = StudentProfileForm(request.POST)
    #TODO: new Student
```

Comment: I think you should look at this: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/11/ajax-form-in-django-with-jqueryform.html It may help you do it right. Nice article about AJAX-ifying your django forms ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which field you are querying, for example:

```
# Query by primary key
student = Student.objects.get(pk = form.get('student_id'))
```

Using non-keyword syntax is also allowed, but ugly. Non-keywords arguments are a special case in Django's query building process, see constructor of the [`Q`](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/db/models/query_utils.py) class if you want to know more.

```
student = Student.objects.get(("pk", form.get('student_id')))
```